# How to get current date?

Tags: ada, duration

Is there a way to get the current date in Ada ?

I'm looking for an equivalent to the C#  `DateTime.Now()` returning a Duration.

I have an event `T` and I want to mesure if `T` started more than 30 seconds ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this in Ada, is to use `Ada.Calendar`, which provides a `Clock` function returning the current `Time`:

```ada
declare
   use type Ada.Calendar.Time;
   Now : constant Ada.Calendar.Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   Interval : constant Duration := 30.0;
begin
   if Now > Start_Time_Of_T + Interval then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Event T took too long");
   end if;
end;
```

Depending on the required precision, you could look at the `Ada.Real_Time` package 
 instead. (The usage is similar, but would required a conversion from `Duration` to `Time_Span`)

Comment: But shouldn’t you require a monotonic clock when you want to measure the time interval between two events? Is the `Clock` function from the package `Ada.Calendar` appropriate in this case?

Comment: @DeeDee, hence my note about `Ada.Real_Time`... However, the 
 question is about an equivalent to `DateTime.Now()`, so I would say `Ada.Calendar` should suffice in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at the `Clock` function in the package `Ada.Real_Time` (see also [ARM D.8](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html)).